# 19.04 I want to create an exact clone of my Ubuntu instance into an iso image

Tags: iso, 19.04, clone

I set up a kiosk system on a computer that I would like to put on other computers. Is there a way to clone my exact instance (with all unique packages I've installed and settings I've changed) and export it into a iso image that would be bootable from a USB.

I see other questions similar to mine but so far all the ones I've come across are really outdated and was unsure if they would still work such as systemback utility.

Comment: just try what those answers suggest and see for yourself ... participants only no spectators

Comment: You can create an image of your current Ubuntu install and extract that to other media using mkusb or Win32Diskimager.